# Update Email not working in Auth Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

So with my code only the email of user in database is changed and not in auth. and other problem is people can also save for example "FakeNotEmail" in the database as email so I want to save valid emails in Auth and Database with rules like in register.

```
    private void updateProfile1(String ChangeEmail) {
    DatabaseReference reference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyUsers").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("email", ChangeEmail);

    reference.updateChildren(hashMap);

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().updateEmail(ChangeEmail);
}
```

Comment: No error in the logcat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `updateEmail()` method of `Auth` is not working because as documentation say:

> To set a user's email address, the user **must have signed in
> recently**.

So you have to login again the user and just after that, update the email, for example in the success login callback.

About your second issue you can perform input checks from your code before perform the update method with the parameters.